# Is it permissible to recite any random ayah of the Quran repeatedly like a dhikr?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, dhikr, makruh

So I read that reciting the Quran is the best dhikr and there is reward with reciting every letter of the Quran. If that's the case, can I take any random ayah and recite it again and again as a form of dhikr (the way people recite Subhanallah repeatedly)?

I understand that certain ayahs are okay to repeat like dhikr because those are mentioned in the hadith (like Ayat Al-Kursi, last 2 ayahs of Baqarah, etc) and every surah can be repeated like a dhikr as well. But I've never seen any Muslim pick a random ayah that they like and recite it repeatedly like a dhikr, so I'm worried it would be an innovation and count as makruh. Especially if the ayah isn't mentioning Allah in any way.

For example, let's take Surah Yusuf, Ayah 74:

Qaaluu famaa jazaa 'uhuu in kuntum kaadhibeen

(Joseph’s men asked, “What should be the price for theft, if you are lying?”)

This is a completely random ayah. Now let's say I really love this ayah for some reason and I recite it again and again like dhikr, since everyone says Quran is the best dhikr. This ayah does not mention Allah anywhere. Rather it's just a small portion of Yusuf (A.S)'s story. Would it be makruh for me to do this? Or would Allah reward me for it, since it's a verse of the Quran? Is it necessary for an ayah to mention Allah or glorify Him in order to be used as a form of dhikr?

Answer (score 0):

The Prophet Muhammad Peace be upon him said there is a reward of 10 hasanat of each letter in the Quran, and he gave the example like Alif Laa Mim, Alif is for 10 hasanat, in this letters there is no meaning at all, what about the ones that has meaning, "Qaalu famaa jazaa uhuu in kuntum kaadhibeen" it is not only the meaning that makes this ayah superior, it is the fact that it is a spoken phrase from the Almighty Allah himself, that there's no other being that can speak it, repeating this verse, is like repeating a supreme word, who the only Allah the Almighty can speak, that is why it is rewardable, of course you can recite ayahs like zikr, for they are superior than the dhikr you know. They are spoken words of the Almighty, who challenged men to come up with.